# Method swizzling for NSTimer is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime, objective-c-runtime

I am trying to method swizzling for NSTimer in a category. But the swizzling method `swizzling_invalidate` is never call when send message `invalidate` to NSTimer object.

```
#import "NSTimer+Test.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation NSTimer (Test)

+ (void)load {
    Method originalMethod, swizzlingMethod;
    originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(invalidate));
    swizzlingMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(swizzling_invalidate));
    method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzlingMethod);
}

- (void)swizzling_invalidate {
    [self swizzling_invalidate];
}

@end
```

It is so strange that method swizzling for other NSObject is working. Like that:

```
#import "NSUserDefaults+Timing.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation NSUserDefaults (Timing)

+ (void)load {
    Method original, swizzling;
    original = class_getInstanceMethod([self class], @selector(synchronize));
    swizzling = class_getInstanceMethod([self class], @selector(swizzling_synchronize));
    method_exchangeImplementations(original, swizzling);
}

- (BOOL)swizzling_synchronize {
    NSDate *start = [NSDate date];
    BOOL returnValue = [self swizzling_synchronize];
    NSLog(@"%f", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:start]);
    return returnValue;
}

@end
```

Comment: And where is this code located?

Comment: What exactly is not working? Is `load` not called or `swizzling_invalidate`? How did notice the error? What did you try?

Comment: In NSTimer category, I have try method swizzling on other NSObject, it work. It is strange method swizzling not working on NSTimer selector. @Caleb

Comment: `swizzling_invalidate ` is not calling when `[timer invalidate]`.@NikolaiRuhe

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by swizzling `invalidate`? Perhaps there is a better way to achieve the same result.

Comment: Because I want to remove associated object for NSTimer when `invalidate`. Any ideas to run my own code after `invalidate`? @mttrb

Answer (score 4):

The `NSTimer` documentation says:

> You should not attempt to subclass NSTimer.

This almost certainly means that the internals of `NSTimer` are not simple and that method swizzling will be tricky.

I suspect what this actually means is that `NSTimer` is implemented as a class cluster or something similar.  The fact that `NSTimer` is toll-free bridged to Core Foundation strongly suggests it might be.

This article, [Playing with NSTimer](http://www.noodlesoft.com/blog/2010/07/01/playing-with-nstimer/), suggests that `NSTimer` is actually an abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that your `load` method is called only once. Otherwise the loading of `NSTimer` subclasses would switch swizzling back to the original implementation.

Comment: It is called only once. I can add `dispatch_once` to make sure it is called once. But it won't worked either.